# Partial View becomes null after ajax call

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, syncfusion

I have dropdown list in which I am fetching all the trainer details.

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTrainer" style="width:30%" onchange="getTrainer_New(this)">
<option value="All">All</option>
@foreach (var trainerDetails in ViewBag.datasourceTrainerList)
{
<option value="@trainerDetails.ID">@trainerDetails.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Now when I change the value from the GetTrainer_New(), I am calling AJAX call which return the partial view. but the view returns null.

```
function getTrainer_New(selectObject)
{
var values = selectObject.value;
var FilterTagInfo = {};
FilterTagInfo.FilterTagID = "";
FilterTagInfo.Name = "TEST";
FilterTagInfo.TrainerName = document.getElementById("selectTrainer").value;
FilterTagInfo.CategoryID = "MyCategory";

$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action("FilterTrainerName", "Dashboard")",
data: JSON.stringify(FilterTagInfo),
//type: "POST",
type: "GET",
//dataType: "json",
async: true,
dataType: 'html',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
// alert("test1" + data.responseText);
$("#dvResultTrainer").html(data.responseText);
//$("#dvResultTrainer").html(data);
},
error: function (data) {
// debugger;
alert("Error" + data);
$("#dvResultTrainer").html(data.responseText);
}
});
 }
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> FilterTrainerName([FromBody] FilterTagInfo filterTagInfo)
{
//Fetching the Data works fine after ajax call But View is not updating
ViewBag.FilterTags = finalresult.ToList();
return PartialView("_PartialTrainer",ViewBag.FilterTags);
}
```

Here is my DIV in which I am binding the data after ajax call.

```
<div id="dvResultTrainer">
@{
await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialTrainer", (List<FilterTagInfo>)ViewBag.FilterTags);
}
</div>
```

And Here is my partial View Code

```
<ejs-chiplist id="filterTags" selection="Single" click="Filters">
    <e-chips>
        @foreach (var p in (List<FilterTagInfo>)ViewBag.FilterTags)
        {
            <e-chip text="@p.Name" value="@p.ID" enabled="true"></e-chip>
        }
    </e-chips>
</ejs-chiplist>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, we had noticed that the method called to the Controller was HTTP Post, but the AJAX request type was given as Get and also the data and content type differs. Kindly check whether the returned result is proper in your sample.

Refer to the below code snippet:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" id="selectTrainer" style="width:30%" onchange="getTrainer_New(this)">
                <option value="All">All</option>
                @foreach (var trainerDetails in ViewBag.datasourceTrainerList)
                {
                    <option value="@trainerDetails.Code">@trainerDetails.ProductName</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<ejs-scripts></ejs-scripts>
<div id="dvResultTrainer">

</div>
<script>

function getTrainer_New(selectObject) {
        var values = selectObject.value;
        var FilterTagInfo = {};
        FilterTagInfo.FilterTagID = "";
        FilterTagInfo.Name = "TEST";
        FilterTagInfo.TrainerName = document.getElementById("selectTrainer").value;
        FilterTagInfo.CategoryID = "MyCategory";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: { value: JSON.stringify(FilterTagInfo) },
            url: "/Home/Features",
            success: function (result) {
            document.getElementById("dvResultTrainer").style.display = "block";
            $('#dvResultTrainer').html(result);
            }
        });

    }
  
</script>
```

Refer to the sample:

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Chip-1431310655